# RegExp for File URL

Tags: java, regex

I write a RegExp for validate a file URL

```
file:/{2,3}[a-zA-Z0-9]*\\|?/.*
```

for URL like

```
file:/D:/workspace/project/build/libs/myjar-1.0.jar
```

But doesnt work,
am looking for a pattern that matches only URL like this,no other.

Pattern Will return false URLs like

`file:/workspace/project/build/libs/myjar-1.0.jar` 
and 
`file:/D:/workspace/project/build/libs/myjar-1.0`
are will not match

please help

Comment: What context is this?? Because if it has no context to match it just `/file\:.*/i`

Comment: Your range `{2,3}` doesn't even match this.

Comment: file:/[a-zA-Z0-9]*/.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Complete question rewrite**

Given the OP's updated criteria, the regex you're looking for is `file\:\/\w\:\/[^\s]*\.jar`; ensure you enabled `g` (global) and `i` (case-insensitive) modifiers.

See a working example on **[Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/yZ8xX9)**

Comment: Saw that, hence my stating that given your context, @JorgeCampos answer is the most suitable. If you have other criteria (e.g. disallow spaces, require colon) that obviously changes the expression.

Comment: problem is when i validate the url  @JorgeCampos expression is return true when the url is 'file:/workspace/project/build/libs/myjar-1.0.jar' and 'file:/workspace/project/build/libs/myjar-1.0'

Comment: I see your updates to the question, standby while I edit this answer to reflect the 'false' matches.

Comment: Done - see the new answer.

Comment: but it doest work on Chrome :RegExp tester extension .See scrnprt http://prntscr.com/275x8o

Comment: I'm not sure how that extension works, but given that it has options for 'case insensitive' and 'global', I'd suggest checking both those boxes and removing the `/` delimiter and `ig` options when using it to troubleshoot. (e.g. just pop in `file\:\/\w\:\/[^\s]*\.jar`)

Comment: The answer is the same -- the /<expression/<modifiers> syntax is how javascript identifies regular expressions, I simply utilized it to denote the modifiers.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no context or rule your regex should be:

```
/file\:.*/i
```

See it here: http://regex101.com/r/yY5xG6

Comment: When you sai like this, I ask Like this what? same path? same number of directories? Just from D: directory? Just *.jar files? You see, still much vague